# Besides transmutation, is there any way to "speed up" the decay rate of radioactive material?

Tags: radioactivity

I'm well aware of transmutation as a way to effectively make radioactive material decay faster, however that isn't really what I mean.

Doing a quick Google search I found references to several theoretical treatises on the subject, and a few references to experiments with, at best, inconclusive results. Among them, there were a few on the quantum anti-zeno effect, which I already knew about, as well as a couple on something called "field enhanced beta decay" and various methods utilizing lasers. Nevertheless, much to my frustration, there was essentially no example I could find with any sort of empirical testing of these effects. So, I suppose I have two questions:

1. How "good" is the physics behind these claims?
2. Have any of these effects ever been *unequivocally* observed experimentally?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52062/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I looked at those, but none specifically reference any particular methodologies, nor do they address the question of empirical observation.

Comment: have a look at a similar question and the answers here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/nuclear-decay-rate-affected-by-sun-and-quantum-randomness

Comment: There exists the controversial effect of the sun on lifetimes, a new paper here : http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3754 . I think that the answer by @AlanSE in the link above covers the QM aspect.